# I calculated composite scores (mean) out of Likert Scale items. Can I run linear regression with them?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, likert

I am learning about how ordinal data (Likert scale, etc) should not be used to conduct linear regression tests.

I ended up calculating composite scores out of groups of items measured in a likert scale (1-5). Each group has about 5 items and their composite scores were produced by calculating the mean. The numbers ended up being something like 4.22, 3.98, etc instead of 2,3,4,5, etc. Disregard the fact that there are other - perhaps preferred - methods to calculate composite scores. Using this method, is my data now appropriate for calculating linear regression?

Comment: You ceased treating them as ordinal when you added the Likert-items (when averaging them). To add them -- to treat 4+1 as being identical to 3+2 (since you say "5" both times) - and so forth for 3+1 vs 2+2 etc - you *already* assumed they're interval.